# Gradients at each vertex of a triangle with HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, radial-gradients

How can I fill a triangle with gradients starting at its vertices given a color for each vertex?

I'm trying to reproduce something like this:

[image: triangle]

I'm making use of the built in `fill` function from the HTML5 canvas Context2D. I'm trying to avoid having to deal with pixel-by-pixel interpolations based on their distance to the vertices. I fear it wont be as performatic as the built-in `fill` function (?). Also I can't deal with WebGL right now.

I've done a **trick** using radial gradients, but, there are a few problems with my naive approach:

- The colors don't seem to blend well
- The last applied gradient overwrites the others
- The value used in the `radius` variable is arbitrary

OBS: I don't know if it's relevant but, I'm building a triangle strip (indexed geometry actually).

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var v1 = { x: 100, y: 0 };
var v2 = { x: 0, y: 180 };
var v3 = { x: 200, y: 180 };

var radius = 175;

var grd1 = ctx.createRadialGradient(v1.x, v1.y, 0, v1.x, v1.y, radius);
grd1.addColorStop(0, "#FF0000FF");
grd1.addColorStop(1, "#FF000000");

var grd2 = ctx.createRadialGradient(v2.x, v2.y, 0, v2.x, v2.y, radius);
grd2.addColorStop(0, "#00FF00FF");
grd2.addColorStop(1, "#00FF0000");

var grd3 = ctx.createRadialGradient(v3.x, v3.y, 0, v3.x, v3.y, radius);
grd3.addColorStop(0, "#0000FFFF");
grd3.addColorStop(1, "#0000FF00");

ctx.beginPath();

ctx.moveTo(v1.x, v1.y);
ctx.lineTo(v2.x, v2.y);
ctx.lineTo(v3.x, v3.y);

ctx.closePath();

ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFFFF"; // fill with white and apply the gradients on top of it
ctx.fill();

ctx.fillStyle = grd1;
ctx.fill();

ctx.fillStyle = grd2;
ctx.fill();

ctx.fillStyle = grd3;
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="180"></canvas>
```

Comment: can you do a square with upper corners blue, and translate width from top to bottom of 0% to 100%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - The colors don't seem to blend well

For this you can use the [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) property of your 2D context to one of its blend modes, even though in your case the compositing mode `"lighter"` with a black background seems to produce the closest result to your model.

> - The last applied gradient overwrites the others

Thanks to the previous bullet point, it's not the case anymore.

> - The value used in the radius variable is arbitrary

Doesn't look like so to me, it does correspond to the distance between every points of your equilateral triangle and its center, which makes perfect sense.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// reordered to make the same as OP's image
var v1 = { x: 0, y: 180 };
var v2 = { x: 200, y: 180 };
var v3 = { x: 100, y: 0 };

var radius = 180;

var grd1 = ctx.createRadialGradient(v1.x, v1.y, 0, v1.x, v1.y, radius);
grd1.addColorStop(0, "#FF0000FF");
grd1.addColorStop(1, "#FF000000");

var grd2 = ctx.createRadialGradient(v2.x, v2.y, 0, v2.x, v2.y, radius);
grd2.addColorStop(0, "#00FF00FF");
grd2.addColorStop(1, "#00FF0000");

var grd3 = ctx.createRadialGradient(v3.x, v3.y, 0, v3.x, v3.y, radius);
grd3.addColorStop(0, "#0000FFFF");
grd3.addColorStop(1, "#0000FF00");

ctx.beginPath();

ctx.moveTo(v1.x, v1.y);
ctx.lineTo(v2.x, v2.y);
ctx.lineTo(v3.x, v3.y);

ctx.closePath();

// fill with black
ctx.fill();

// set blend mode
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";

ctx.fillStyle = grd1;
ctx.fill();

ctx.fillStyle = grd2;
ctx.fill();

ctx.fillStyle = grd3;
ctx.fill();

// if you need to draw something else, don't forget to reset the gCO
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="180"></canvas>
```